# How to show a harmonic function is a polynomial?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian

Can anyone give me a hint to show the following?

Let $m$ be a positive integer and $u : \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  be a harmonic function. If $u(x) = O(\left|x \right|)^m$ when $\left|x \right| \to \infty$, show that $u$ is polynomial of degree at most $m$.

Any clue will be great.

Thanks

Comment: You mean "a polynomial of degree at most $m$"?

Comment: Do you know an/the interior estimate for harmonic functions?

Comment: yes, thanks. @TeddantheTerran

Comment: Do not know @hal4math